# Hyperbolic surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=S_1\times S_1−Δ$ , where $Δ=\{(x,y)∈S_1\times S_1|x=y\}$.

I know that this is (one of the) usual model for the cylinder , but how to proof that it is a hyperbolic surface?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm fairly certain its not hyperbolic, it has Euler characteristic 0 and curvature 0. It would be flat.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete answer:

We say a surface $\Sigma$ admits a hyperbolic metric if there exists a complete, finite area, Riemannian metric on $\Sigma$ of constant curvature $-1$. We then have the following theorem,

*Thm.* Let $\Sigma$ be any surface (possibly with punctures of boundary). If the Euler characteristic $\chi(\Sigma)<0$ then $\Sigma$ admits a hyperbolic metric. If $\chi(\Sigma)=0$ then $\Sigma$ admits a Euclidean metric.

Since the cylinder $C$ has $\chi(C)=0$ it admits a Euclidean metric.

Comment: Thanks alot for your respond. I have read that the sphere with two puncture point may homeomorphic to cylinder with Euclidean geometry or homeomorphic to psudosphere with hyperbolic geometry. In this cituation in my quistion it should be hyperbolic.
But I really don't know how to prove that??
Any help please Sara

Comment: Oh I see, the pseudosphere is in fact homeomorphic to a cylinder and can be realized by the quotient of the hyperbolic plane by the group of limit rotations generated by $t(z)=2\pi+z$. Since the group acts geometrically on the hyperbolic plane, the pseudosphere has a natural hyperbolic structure.